# How to print two different random lines from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, text-files

I need to print two different random lines from text file. Below is the code to print one line, how would I make it print two different lines rather than the possibility of two the same.

```
import random
with open('Long films') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a `k` length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
import random
with open('Long films') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.sample(lines, 2))
```

If you are looking for non-unique lines, use `random.choices` instead.

Answer (score 3):

use `sample`

```
import random
with open('Long films') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.sample(lines, 2))
```